# How the access grant goes in OAuth2 when Resource Owner is already single signed-in

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have been reading the OAuth2 specs the whole evening :) To my understanding the Authorization Service asks the Resource Owner to give permission to the Client. The Resource Owner can then grant access e.g. by providing username/password. However, what if the Resource Owner is already Single-Signed On by the enterprise, then no credentials should be required to be given, right? How does the flow go in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Same flow except that the user doesn't explicitly need to authenticate since he's got an SSO session running. The consent step where the Authorization Server asks the Resource Owner to give permission is independent of the user authentication or SSO and will stay the same. Or to put it differently: the consent step is a separate screen that is presented only after the login phase. A login prompt may be skipped if there's an existing SSO session, the consent step is not.

Comment: But how does this look in practice? If user has a SSO session, the Authentication Service must somehow be able to verify this session.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that I didn't quite understand what you meant with the Authentication part... Do you mean that the authentication part is totally separate from the Authorisation flow I described?

Comment: yes, the authentication part is indeed totally separate from the authorization part; in fact OAuth doesn't specify at all how to authenticate users (well except in the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant, which is for migration purposes only)

Comment: Is it possible to pass the user authentication credentials somehow in Oauth2? if not, how does the Authentication Server indeed know the user is a user that has been authorized access to the Resources Server? I know there is a specific grant type where Resource Owner gives username/password, but if this is not used, how is the Resource Owner identified, if its authentication credentials are never passed forward?

Comment: as pointed out, OAuth itself doesn't specify authentication; how the authorization server authenticates the user is left to the discretion of the server itself (could use a username/password); I advise you to read: http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Comment: I read the page, but didn't get much smarter, to be honest :) I read this though, which I think was great: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1208_rasmussen/1208_rasmussen.html

My problem with that page is the flow in Figure 3 step 3. It describes the Authorization Code grant type. However, step 3 states "The authorization server authenticates the resource owner." but does not state how, and against what? Is the user logged in and session passed to Auth Server, or is user prompted with username/password?